# How to write and calculate hash of a file without closing it in between

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to calculate MD5 of a file right after writing it:

```
   std::wstring filePath = L"file.txt";
   auto hFile = CreateFile(
            filePath.c_str(),
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            FILE_SHARE_READ,
            NULL,
            OPEN_ALWAYS,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
            NULL); 
   //writing to file with WriteFile(hFile, buffer, DWORD(size), &written, NULL))
```

Now if I close it and reopen it's OK.

But I'm trying to calculate MD5 without closing it.
To be sure that pointer is set to correct position, I also tried to save a pointer to file's end:

```
    LARGE_INTEGER liOfs = {0};
    LARGE_INTEGER liNew = {0};
    SetFilePointerEx(hFile, liOfs, &liNew, FILE_CURRENT);
    SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
    auto md5 = CalculateMd5(hFile); // md5 is correct here
    // restore pointer
    SetFilePointerEx(hFile, liNew, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
```

So, I'm getting exception at `CloseHandle(hFile)`: `0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified`.

And there is MD5 calculating:

```
std::string GetMD5HashOfFile(HANDLE hFile)
    {
        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile) {
            return {};
        }

        HCRYPTPROV hProv = 0;
        if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) {
            return {};
        }

        HCRYPTHASH hHash = 0;
        if (!CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash)) {
            CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
            return {};
        }

        static constexpr int BUFSIZE = 1024;
        DWORD cbRead = 0;
        BYTE rgbFile[BUFSIZE];
        BOOL bResult = FALSE;
        while (bResult = ReadFile(hFile, rgbFile, BUFSIZE, &cbRead, NULL)) {
            if (0 == cbRead) {
                break;
            }

            if (!CryptHashData(hHash, rgbFile, cbRead, 0)) {
                CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
                CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
                return {};
            }
        }

        if (!bResult) {
            CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
            CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
            return {};
        }

        static constexpr int MD5LEN = 16;
        CHAR rgbDigits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
        BYTE rgbHash[MD5LEN];
        DWORD cbHash = MD5LEN;
        if (CryptGetHashParam(hHash, HP_HASHVAL, rgbHash, &cbHash, 0)) {
            std::ostringstream oss;
            for (auto c : rgbHash) {
                oss.fill('0');
                oss.width(2);
                oss << std::hex << static_cast<int>(c);
            }

            CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
            CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
            return oss.str();
        }
        else {
            CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
            CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
            return {};
        }

        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);

        return {};
    }
```

Here is the test program:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    const std::wstring filePath = L"test.txt";
    auto               r        = DeleteFile(filePath.c_str());
    if (!r) {
        auto e = GetLastError();
        if (e != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
            std::cout << e << '\n';
            return -1;
        }
    }

    auto hFile = CreateFile(filePath.c_str(),
                            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                            FILE_SHARE_READ,
                            NULL,
                            OPEN_ALWAYS,
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
                            NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return -1;
    }
    DWORD              written = 0;
    const std::wstring buffer  = L"Hello, world.";
    const auto         size    = buffer.length() * sizeof(wchar_t);
    if (!WriteFile(hFile, buffer.c_str(), size, &written, NULL)) {
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return -1;
    }

    if (size != written) {
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return -1;
    }

    /*CloseHandle(hFile);
    hFile = CreateFile(filePath.c_str(),
                       GENERIC_READ,
                       FILE_SHARE_READ,
                       NULL,
                       OPEN_EXISTING,
                       FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
                       NULL);*/

    LARGE_INTEGER liOfs = { 0 };
    LARGE_INTEGER liNew = { 0 };
    SetFilePointerEx(hFile, liOfs, &liNew, FILE_CURRENT);
    auto md5 = GetMD5HashOfFile(hFile);
    std::cout << "MD5: " << md5 << '\n';
    SetFilePointerEx(hFile, liNew, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't throw exception. But it somehow calculates incorrect hash: app's MD5 is `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`, and cmd tool shows another - `1207b6ae90980a5b039d57384b8bbd26`. If I uncomment lines in the middle hashes are equal, but still no exception. Command to check hash is:

```
certutil -hashfile test.txt MD5
```

**UPDATE**: I'm really sorry. It's a third question where I cann't debug my app properly. Actually, the file was closed twice, hence the exception. I swear, I'll try to do something with myself).
The only question left: is it possible to calculate file hash properly, because without closing the file handle in between gives a wrong hash.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] that reproduces the issue.

Comment: `SetFilePointer` senseless api. never need use it

Comment: Make a memory mapped view of your file and you can work with that  : [reading-and-writing-from-a-file-view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/reading-and-writing-from-a-file-view)

Comment: CloseHandle doesn't throw exceptions.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - `CloseHandle` (`NtClose`) raise exception if handle is invalid and debugger attach to process

Comment: There is no need to reset the file position before closing the file handle. Also, it would be more efficient to calculate the MD5 *while* you are writing bytes to the file, rather than waiting until *after* all of the bytes have been written and then re-read though the entire file. That is just wasted time and overhead. For example: `hHash = CryptCreateHash(...); ... hFile = CreateFile(...); while (WriteFile(hFile, data, size, &written, NULL)) { CryptHashData(hHash, data, written, 0); } CloseHandle(hFile); ... CryptDestroyHash(hHash);`